# Getting indices of elemenst of list that meet certain expression - Wolfram Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, where-clause

Is there method to get indices of certain elements of list Wolfram Mathematica ?. For visualisation of problem say I have two list,
{2,3,4,5} and {s1,s2,s3,s4}. I want to take indices of even elements of first list so in return get {1,3} and that get coresponding elements from second list that is s1,s3. I know there is Select[] method but this take elements not indices Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

First, let

```
l1 = {2, 3, 4, 5}; l2 = {s1, s2, s3, s4};
```

then this

```
Pick[l2, EvenQ[l1]]
```

seems to satisfy your immediate requirement.  In other situations `Position` might be useful too.

Oh, and you might like to know about https://mathematica.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches:

```
set1 = {2, 3, 4, 5}
set2 = {s1, s2, s3, s4}
Pick[set2, EvenQ /@ set1]
Extract[set2, Position[set1, _?EvenQ]]
```

**Edit:**

The first approach is essentially the same as Mark's answer, but he takes advantage of the `Listable` attribute of `EvenQ`.